# Синхронизация сайта с платежным терминалом, как?

Tags: php, платежи, платежные-терминалы

Доброе время суток! Каким образом синхронизируются сайты с платежным терминалом? Например вконтакте и т.д, - то есть человек пополняет баланс через терминал  (вводит определенную сумму) тот его обрабатывает (анализируя логин, id, или телефон пользователя на сайте) и отправляет информацию на сайт, для которого и была произведена оплата, на профиле пользователя (человека) на сайте в своей очереди отображается информация об начислении баланса.

Цель: Каким образом (технологией) взаимодействует и в общем как производиться прием оплаты на сайте через платежный терминал. Пожалуйста покажите пример файла который и может обрабатывать информацию об начислении платежа (который в своем очереди передает платежный терминал).

Comment: В смысле вам надо что б кошельки на вашем сайте пополнялись с терминала?

Comment: Грубо... заключается договор с компанией платёжного терминала, они при оплате, по зараннее оговоремному алгоритму будут менятся "файлами". Возможно SOAP возможно REST. Возможно запросы будут шифрованые и или подписаные.

Comment: @nick_n_a "В смысле вам надо что б кошельки на вашем сайте пополнялись с терминала" - да